# nRF24L01 only getting 10 meters range!

Tags: arduino-uno, nrf24l01+

I am making a project where I need to communicate between two devices that are about 300-500 meters apart and might experience a lot of RF interference and obstacles. So I thought for initial testing the nRF24L01 modules will be good knowing that they are advertised at 500m. When I did a range test, I got only 10 meters and that too with no obstacles in between! This module seems to be the only choice I have so any suggestions on how to increase range will help immensely.

Stats:

nRF24L01+ module with PCB antennae and a socket adapter board.
I am using the nRFLite library and am transmitting at 2MBPS and have tried multiple channels!

Comment: a quick internet search reveals that you need an external antenna to achieve the communication range you require

Comment: Not directly related to nRF24L01, but I tested ESP-01 with PCB antenna running ESP-Now protocol, with small payload of about 40 bytes. I got about 250-300m without obstacles. But if there is obstacles (even just some trees), the distance reduced significantly and external antenna would be required.

Comment: The nRF24L01+ is only rated to about 10m. You can get modules with an additional power amplifier and antenna that boosts the range, but the standard range of a bare nRF14L01+ is only about 10m. For example, my K780 keyboard, which uses the SOC equivalent of the nRF24L01+ has in the specs "Powerful wireless connection with 10m/33ft range"